# How can I make data from form1 accessible to form2 in different post events for razor pages without the use of static types?

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-4.0, razor-pages

I am essentially trying to access data from form1 in form2 post event handler. I have two forms on the same page with two different post event handlers that trigger based on which button is pressed. My issue here is, once my second post event handler is trigger all of the data from form1 becomes out of scope and inaccessible. The only way so far I was able to make this work is by using static types but I would prefer not to use static types as they can cause problems if not handled properly. I have provided a code snippet of what I am essentially trying to accomplish. I have looked at other posts but I can't find one similar to my scenario.

```
public PageProperty form1; //I can switch this to static type to accomplish my needs but I am trying to find a better way to do this.        

public void OnPostSubmitForm1(PageProperty form1Data)
{
        form1 = form1Data; //gives form1 data
}

public void OnPostSubmitForm2(PageProperty  form2Data)
{
        PageProperty form2 = form1; //comes back as null if I don't use static type
}
```

Comment: Maybe include more code.  (including the forms)  Doesn't seem like you'd get anything but the view data with static... (so no changed form fields)  You may just want one form and two buttons here.

Comment: You can set the session for your form1 data. Session can be accessed from each request.

Comment: @Rena that is possible but I don't want to rely on using session variables for 30+ pages. Any other way I can do this?

Comment: Hi @user2785460, seems not. If so, i will suggest you to use just one form with two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the Form One data somewhere. Instead of trying to save it statically server-side, you could save it in your browser's Local Store and then submit it with your form2 data.

Comment: I am trying to do this without relying on local storage.